# materializecss in messes with existing classes. How can I add a prefix?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, materialize

I want to use materializecss in my chrome extension.
The extension adds some functionality to gmail. Unfortunately the materializecss seems to interfere with the gmail stylings. Is it possible to isolate the scope of the materialize css or to add a custom prefix to the classes?

I currently import the css in my manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://mail.google.com/*"],
      "css": [
        "vendor/materializecss/materialize.min.css"
      ],
...
```

Comment: No. You'll have to modify the CSS file manually, or use an iframe, or a scoped style element. Search the answers showing how to isolate styles.

Answer (score 0):

Not without rewriting the whole framework (the scss files) or using scoped stlyes.

Comment: I have added prefixes using gulp plugin. But this solved only css file, how can I update JS file? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is `gulp-class-prefix` plugin to prefix CSS classes. Here is the configuration file

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    classPrefix = require('gulp-class-prefix');

gulp.task('prefix', function () {
    return gulp.src('SOURCE_OF_CSS_FILE')
        .pipe(classPrefix('YOUR_PREFIX'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('DESTINASTION_FOLDER'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['prefix']);
```

but this will only prefix only CSS file and will work only for the components that do not need JS inclusion. For dynamic components, you need to make changes in **materiazecss.js** file.

**Update**

I got this [python script](https://gist.github.com/macanderson/6128137). This script is designed for bootstrap. But anyhow this works(70%-80%) for materializecss too. You just need to change the file name in the main function of it ie replace bootstrap with materializecss.